# Are these technologies futuristic or are they already being used in real life?

Tags: internal-consistency, power-sources, medical

My world is strictly FUTURE, which means technologies that we humans on real- modern day Earth have achieved are not given the spotlight. They just blend into the background. However, I don't know about these 3 technologies. Are they in the use or are they still not yet developed?

1. Using Ammonia to store energy
2. Molecular modelling engine to speed up drug discovery
3. Magnetic resonance mass spectrometry to diagnose diseases from a drop of urine

I know this might be too broad, but the science stack exchange always take forever to answer questions. I was wondering if any science buffs could help me out

Comment: What has your independent research revealed?

Comment: If you are unsure if a question is too broad we have a resource on [meta] called the sandbox that allows you to get feedback on a question before asking it on the main site.

Comment: Whether a technology is "futuristic or not" is a complicated question. There's a big difference between a technology that is theoretically possible and one that has become a commodity product. Steel has been around since antiquity but it was only recently when high performance alloys became readily available in bulk. You're going to need to clarify what you mean by futuristic before this question is answerable.

Comment: Google is your friend. Indeed, from just a quick search I myself found that both 1 and 2 are currently in use (though not widespread) and 3 is being held back by certain government policies concerning which information banks can be used to diagnose patients (though the technique itself is in fact ready for implementation).

Comment: On this site it's conventional to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer so that people from every time zone have a chance to weigh in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, there are microbes capable of using it
2. Yes there are, and they are in use.
3. No, while some diseases can be diagnosed from urine, a great many cannot. The toxic nature of urine can easily kill bacteria and viruses so many won't survive long enough to be discoverable in any test.